# Noise in headphones when connected to laptop

Tags: linux, laptop, arch-linux, alsa, pulse-audio

I have a Dell m4800 laptop, with arch linux installed. Everytime I connect my headphones to the computer I hear a regular noise but just when no other sound is being played from computer.

I am sure this problem is software related, this did not happened when the computer has windows (installed by default) and do not occur when; e.g. I put in `pause` a song. So I think this is (software related) something with pulse, alsa or the driver.

I have the operating system updated, and no special configuration was made. These are the audio devices listed by `lspci`

```
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
```

Do you have any ideas about what could be wrong this ?

Comment: Not much help, I'm sure, but on an iPhone I traced such a noise down to the wireless interface "beaconing" at regular intervals.  It went away when I turned the wireless LAN off.

Comment: It just shows that while linux in general is nice and does the main tasks, it is not really suitable as a desktop replacement. And while it made huge steps towards this in the past decade, Windows and MacOS are making bigger steps.

Comment: I tried disabling wifi, unpluggin power cable, but problem stills there, but thank you @DanielRHicks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's an common problem with this model. The solution seems to be plugging it into a dockingstation instead of directly into the laptop.

You could try to use the alsamixer to filter the sound.

Comment: Oh, sad to hear that and I have no a docking station. About alsamixer I tried the Auto-Mute Mode to Disabled but it does not solve the problem. But thank you @Jaxhead, will still searching about how to deal with this